# Animate selectors to it's original style, bad or OK?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Should I use `$button.eq(number_of_active_slide)` or `$button` in the example below?

The height of all buttons are 10px except for one which has the index of `different_value`.

In `Option A` I will be able to cache the selectors in a variable, which seems good to me. But I will animate all the selectors (most of them will already have a height of 10px). So it seems unnecessary.

In `Option B` I will not be able to cache the selectors in a variable (it will be a different value every time it is clicked). But I will online animate a single selector which also seems god to me.

**Example:**

```
// Option A:
$button.click(function () {

    $button.animate({
        height: '10px'
    }, 500);

});

// Option B:
$button.click(function () {

    $button.eq(different_value).animate({
        height: '10px'
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you can, please preapere a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this:

```
$button.click(function () {

    $(this).animate({
        height: '10px'
    }, 500);

});
```

I am assuming that the button you click is the one you want to animate.

If this is not the case, .eq() is a super-fast operation. You are still caching the set of buttons, which is the expensive searching step. Using .eq() to reduce the set is not bad. I would use option B in that case.